# Lua Missing } unexpected

Tags: syntax, lua

```
function love.load()
Tileset = love.graphics.newImage('countryside.png')

TileW, TileH = 32, 32
local tilesetW, tilesetH = Tileset:getWidth(), Tileset:getHeight()

Quads = {
    love.graphics.newQuad(0, 0, TileW, TileH, tilesetW, tilesetH) -- 1 = grass
    love.graphics.newQuad(32, 0, TileW, TileH, tilesetW, tilesetH) -- 2 = box
    love.graphics.newQuad(0, 32, TileW, TileH, tilesetW, tilesetH) -- 3 = flowers
    love.graphics.newQuad(32, 32, TileW, TileH, tilesetW, tilesetH) -- 4 = box
}

TileTable = {
    {1, 1, 1},
    {1, 2, 1},
    {1, 1, 1}
}

end
```

This code gives this error:

Syntax error: main.lua:9: '}' expected (to close '{' at line 7) near 'love'

I don't understand it. Anyone got any help?

Comment: You are missing a comma from the end of those lines inside the list `Quad`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Lua, an array is initialized as below, hope it helps:

```
Quads = {
    love.graphics.newQuad(0, 0, TileW, TileH, tilesetW, tilesetH), -- 1 = grass
    love.graphics.newQuad(32, 0, TileW, TileH, tilesetW, tilesetH), -- 2 = box
    love.graphics.newQuad(0, 32, TileW, TileH, tilesetW, tilesetH), -- 3 = flowers
    love.graphics.newQuad(32, 32, TileW, TileH, tilesetW, tilesetH), -- 4 = box
}
```